# how to use LinearGradient in flutter with transform?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

> how to use LinearGradient in flutter with transform?

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: [Colors.black, Colors.white],
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    transform: ???,
  )
 ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GradientRotation` class, which extends the `GradientTransform` class. It takes an angle in radians as an argument and rotates the `shader` in the clockwise direction

Here is an example of  `GradientRotation`:

```
Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Text(title,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white)),
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            transform: GradientRotation(pi/2),
            colors: [
              color.withOpacity(0.5),
              color.withOpacity(0.55),
              color.withOpacity(0.65),
              color.withOpacity(0.75),
              color.withOpacity(0.85),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.centerRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
```

Here are the snapshots of the application of `GradientRoation`:

[image: Without GradientRotation]

[image: With 90 degree rotation in clockwise direction]

In the first image, I have not used `GradientRotation`; in the second image, I have passed 90 degrees (`pi/2` radians) as an argument and, as a result it, has been rotated in the clockwise direction by 90 degrees.

Try to hot reload your application to see the change if hot restart fails.

Comment: thanks for your answer bro but i done work around to this already :)

Comment: @ParthPitroda 
No probs ! 
I saw there was no explanation about this issue,